# how to display a word document into a JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, iframe

by the time I show in an Iframe pdf files but I would like to display files. doc,. ptt, xls in Iframe

Use this Jquery to display pdf files

```
$("#Iframe").html(" <iframe src=\"archivos/"+nombre+"\" width=\"400\" height=\"500\"scrolling=\"auto\" \n\
        frameborder=\"1\"> </iframe>");
```

Comment: So what makes you believe the browser is capable of displaying these files in the first place?

Comment: There are services like DROPBOX or Google Drive
and they show these documents

Comment: I have the idea of ​​converting the documents to pdf but how feasible is it?